# What could be an efficient SublistQ command?

Tags: list-manipulation

I know about `SubsetQ` but I could not find `SublistQ` such that `SublistQ[a, b]` would be true if and only if `b` is a sublist of `a` (that is, `a` has form `Join[x, b, y]` for some `x`, `y`).

I came up with

```
mySublistQ[a_, b_] := 
 With[{lb = Length[b] - 1}, 
  lb < 0 \[Or] 
   Or @@ Map[
     With[{try = Drop[a, First[#]]}, 
       Length[try] >= lb \[And] Take[try, lb] == Rest[b]] &, Position[a, First[b]]]]
```

Can one do better?

Comment: Not sure if it is efficient but this seems quite close to what you wrote in your explanation: `MatchQ[a, {x___, Sequence @@ b, y___}]` or `MatchQ[a, {x___, Splice@b, y___}]`

Comment: @userrandrand Sorry I had to correct mine. Seems like yours should be OK. Although there already is a solution in an answer, maybe it still would be useful if you add yours as an answer?

Comment: I am not sure the title modification accurately depicts the original title as coolest could mean efficient+elegant or just elegant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the following functions:

```
Clear[sublistQ]; 
sublistQ[a_, b_] := 
 Catch[MovingMap[If[# == b, Throw[True], False] &, a, Length@b - 1]; 
  False]

Clear[sublistQ2];

sublistQ2[a_, b_] := MatchQ[a, {x___, Sequence @@ b, y___}]
```

I also considered @Syed's LongestCommonSubsequence method out of curiosity and added the SequenceCount function

```
 sublistQ3[a_, b_] := SequenceCount[a, b] > 0
```

---

#### Test example and benchmark :

Consider the question of whether the first $n$ digits of $ \exp(1)=e$ appear in the first $m$ digits of $\pi$:

Below we consider 6 digits of the Euler number $ \exp(1)=e$ and at most $5\times10^7$ digits of $\pi$

```
a = First@RealDigits[N[Pi, 5*10^7]]; 

b = First@RealDigits[N[E, 6]];
```

The image below shows the evolution of how long each method takes to check whether the statement is True or False. Note that the answer is always True for the ranges I took so theoretically a fast algorithm would take a near constant time.

```
tab1 = Table[{n, First@AbsoluteTiming@sublistQ[a[[1 ;; n]], b]}, {n, 
    Subdivide[5*10^5, 5*10^7, 10]}];

tab2 = Table[{n, First@AbsoluteTiming@sublistQ2[a[[1 ;; n]], b]}, {n, 
    Subdivide[5*10^5, 5*10^7, 10]}];

tab3 = Table[{n, First@AbsoluteTiming@mySublistQ[a[[1 ;; n]], b]}, {n,
     Subdivide[5*10^5, 5*10^7, 10]}];

tab4 = Table[{n, First@AbsoluteTiming@sublistQ3[a[[1 ;; n]], b]}, {n, 
    Subdivide[5*10^5, 5*10^7, 10]}];
```

I also checked that they all agreed on true or false.

> Timing as a function of the size of the first list for which we ask whether the second list is a member of. The answer is True for each point below. The scale is linear.

[image]

---

Consider now **fixing the big list** and **increasing the length of the small list**:

```
b = First@RealDigits[N[E, 7]];
a = First@RealDigits[N[Pi, 5*10^7]];


 tab1 = Table[{n, First@AbsoluteTiming@sublistQ[a, b[[1 ;; n]]]}, {n, 
    2, 7}];
tab2 = Table[{n, First@AbsoluteTiming@sublistQ2[a, b[[1 ;; n]]]}, {n, 
    2, 7}];
tab3 = Table[{n, First@AbsoluteTiming@mySublistQ[a, b[[1 ;; n]]]}, {n,
     2, 7}];
tab4 = Table[{n, First@AbsoluteTiming@sublistQ3[a, b[[1 ;; n]]]}, {n, 
    2, 7}];

ListLogPlot[{tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Purple, Brown, Black}, 
 PlotLegends -> {MovingMap, MatchQ, LongestCommonSubsequence, 
   SequenceCount}]
```

> Timing as a function of the size of the second list for which we ask whether the first list contains it. The vertical scale (y-axis) is logarithmic.

[image]

---

Now consider the case of a long subsequence that is not present:

```
b = First@RealDigits[N[E, 8]];

a = First@RealDigits[N[Pi, 5*10^7]];
```

Timing below in seconds

> MovingMap

```
 {50.1696, False}
```

> LongestCommonSubsequence

```
{3.70687, False}
```

> MatchQ

```
{1.59695, False}
```

> SequenceCount

```
{0.109687, False}
```

Comment: Great! So the `MatchQ` version seems to be the champion?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Not sure, maybe one could make an association between symbols in the list and integers and then use some fancy listable function that threads through the list or just a while loop with `Compile` after making the association/map to integers.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე thank you for the accept but consider waiting a day or 2 to see what other answers you get.

Comment: Well, I could reaccept later if something still better shows up. Right now yours seems to be too cool to wait any longer :D

Comment: thanks (:. There is a rumor that some users do not consider questions that are already accepted. That does not seem likely to me given that practically everyone knows that it is possible that the accepted answer might not be the best..

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  I tested Syed's SequenceCount and it's the fastest: `sublistQ3[a_, b_] := SequenceCount[a, b] > 0` rather strange as it does more than what is necessary.

Comment: Strange... something else must be going on behind the scenes. Is it possible to find out what does `SequenceCount` use?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I do not know why it's that fast. Consider accepting Syed's answer that provides the quickest method.

Comment: You see, yours still contains more information - including efficiency comparisons, etc.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე sure but the accepted answer should be the best answer to the question itself. A benchmark is just further details.The fastest and most elegant answer is Syed's answer. As an example consider someone that puts up a one liner that is better than 10 other users and someone just comes along, adds a timing comparison table without having to think much and gets more points than anyone else. The most fairest choice is to accept Syed's answer.

Comment: Imo informativeness is still highest priority. Answers are all here, readers can compare them and judge by themselves.

Answer (score 6):

```
subListQ[lst_, sublst_]:=!(SequenceCases[lst, sublst,1]==={})
```

Examples:

```
lst1={1,2,3,4,6,7};
lst2={2,3,4};
lst3={2,3,4,7};

subListQ[lst1,lst2]
subListQ[lst1,lst3]
subListQ[lst1,lst1]

True
False
True
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a rich collection of `Sequence*` functions in Mathematica to do this. Let's create a minimal example and use `SubsetQ` for comparison later on.

```
a = Range[1, 20];
b = {4, 2, 3};
c = Range[11, 15];

{SubsetQ[a, b], SubsetQ[a, c]}
```

> {True, True}

Now define:

```
mySublistQ[a_, b_] := LongestCommonSubsequence[a, b] == b

{mySublistQ[a, b], mySublistQ[a, c]}
```

{False, True}

---

`Sequence*` functions can be a bit slow at times. An alternative approach using `DeleteCases` could be:

```
f2[a_, b_] := 
 MemberQ[Partition[DeleteCases[a, _?(! MemberQ[b, #] &)], Length@b], 
  b]

{f2[a, b], f2[a, c]}
```

> {False, True}

This would still not be a comprehensive solution for
multiple/overlappping copies

---

The more natural way to find overlaps and multiple copies (if required) can be done with `Sequence*` functions. Consider:

```
a = {2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3}
b = {1, 4, 1}

SequenceCases[a, b, Overlaps -> All]
```

> {{1, 4, 1}, {1, 4, 1}, {1, 4, 1}}

```
SequencePosition[a, b, Overlaps -> All]
```

> {{3, 5}, {5, 7}, {9, 11}}

and

```
SequenceCount[a, b, Overlaps -> All]
```

> 3

I have developed a deeper appreciation of `Sequence*` functions.

Comment: Nice. maybe also `Cases[a, _?(MemberQ[b, #] &)] == b` which avoids double negation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Another way could be  `Select[a, MemberQ[b, #] &] == b`

Comment: I just thought of that and was going to mention it haha

Comment: Great! One question: would all these also work correctly if there are several (maybe overlapping) instances of `b` as a sublist of `a`?

Comment: Actually I think if there are many duplicates in `a` that are also in `b` then the length from Select would be larger than b and so it would not work. For example `b={2}` and `a={2,2,1,4,2,2}`

Comment: Updated, although `Sequence*` functions are the built-in solution for such purposes.

Comment: There also ContainsAll, ContainsExactly, ContainsAny, ContainsOnly, ContainsNone to your disposition, which are fast. In your case, for example, ContainsAll[a,b] should be enough

Comment: @Acus Both `ContainsAll[{1,2},{2,1}]` and `ContainsAll[{1,2},{1,1}]` would give false positives, for example.

Answer (score 3):

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4};
b = {2, 3, 4};
c = {2, 3, 4, 7};
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
sub[{a_, b_}] := MemberQ[b] @ SequenceSplit[a, x : b :> x]
```

```
sub /@ {{a, b}, {a, c}, {b, b}, {b, Reverse @ b}}
```

> {True, False, True, False}

Answer (score 3):

```
lst1={1,2,3,4,6,7};

lst2={2,3,4};

lst3={2,3,4,7};
```

---

Grabbing the @user1066's examples, my attempt is the following:

```
subListQ[a_, b_] := Module[{pos},
  pos = List@*Span @@@ MinMax /@ 
        Split[Position[a, Alternatives @@ b], #2[[1]] - #1[[1]] == 1 &];
  SameQ[DeleteCases[Extract[a, pos], b], {}]]

subListQ[lst1, lst2]
subListQ[lst1, lst3]
subListQ[lst1, lst1]

True

False

True
```

Testing `subListQ` with @eldo's examples:

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4};
b = {2, 3, 4};
c = {2, 3, 4, 7};

subListQ[#1, #2] & @@@ {{a, b}, {a, c}, {b, b}, {b, Reverse@b}}
```

> `{True, False, True, False}`